PostgreSQL ERROR invalid input syntax for type date; no null fields
I am trying to do a simple copy/import from a CSV file in PGAdmin but I'm getting an error "invalid input syntax for type date" for the date field. The format of the date field within the CSV file is YYYY-MM-DD, if that's of concern.
I'm working with PGAdmin 4.8.7 (desktop) and PostgreSQL 16.3.2. The script is as follows:
copy "Feb24_Primary_Ballot_Distribution" 
(
    "ELECTION_DATE",
    "VOTER_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER",
    "LAST_NAME",
    "SUFFIX",
    "FIRST_NAME",
    "MIDDLE_NAME",
    "ADDRESS_LINE_ONE",
    "ADDRESS_LINE_TWO",
    "CITY",
    "STATE",
    "ZIP_CODE",
    "MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_ONE",
    "MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_TWO",
    "MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_THREE",
    "MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_FOUR",
    "MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_FIVE",
    "COUNTY_CODE",
    "COUNTY_NAME",
    "JURISDICTION_CODE",
    "JURISDICTION_NAME",
    "PARTY_CODE"
    )
    FROM 'E:\PostgreSQL\PostgreSQL QVF DB\Source Spreadsheets\02-24 Primary ballot distribution\RepDemTest2.csv' WITH NULL '' DELIMITER ',' CSV ENCODING 'WIN1252' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE ''''; 

and the resulting process feedback looks like:
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "ELECTION_DATE"
CONTEXT:  COPY Feb24_Primary_Ballot_Distribution, line 1, column ELECTION_DATE: "ELECTION_DATE" 

SQL state: 22007

RepDemTest2.csv consists of four records:
"ELECTION_DATE","VOTER_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER","LAST_NAME","SUFFIX","FIRST_NAME","MIDDLE_NAME","ADDRESS_LINE_ONE","ADDRESS_LINE_TWO","CITY","STATE","ZIP_CODE","MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_ONE","MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_TWO","MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_THREE","MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_FOUR","MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_FIVE","COUNTY_CODE","COUNTY_NAME","JURISDICTION_CODE","JURISDICTION_NAME","PARTY_CODE"
"2024-02-27","1445005264","SMITH","","TERRY","W","82 10TH ST","","SEBEWAING","MI","48759","","","","","","323","HURON","72200","SEBEWAING TOWNSHIP","REP"
"2024-02-27","8526014","SMITH","","VAN","LESLIE","445 S LACHANCE RD","","LAKE CITY","MI","49651","","","","","","573","MISSAUKEE","44380","LAKE TOWNSHIP","REP"
"2024-02-27","34159114","SMITH","","BEVERLY","ANN","359 S AUSABLE RIVER DR","","LUZERNE","MI","48636","28 SCHORN DR","","LAKE ORION","MI","48362","68","OSCODA","08220","BIG CREEK TOWNSHIP","DEM"
"2024-02-27","1444444","SMITH","","DEAN","LEONARD","46 SELMA RD","","SKANDIA","MI","49885","","","","","","52","MARQUETTE","74110","SKANDIA TOWNSHIP","DEM"

Note the ELECTION_DATE fields are all populated.
I had seen some feedback regarding the effect of empty/null date fields, so I created a test CSV file for which I can be certain there are no null values in the date field, to no avail; the error persists. I had also tried adding "WITH NULL ''" after the source file in the FROM statement as I had seen suggested, with no effect.

Please share the exact command instead of a vague description. The data you try to insert, could that be an empty string “” ?

Need a lot more information. Add as text update to question text: 1) Postgres version. 2) Complete COPY command. 3) Complete error message. 4) Sample of the data. 5) What part of pgAdmin are you doing this in?

"PARTY_CODE" "2024-02-27", there is a comma missing between these two.

PARTY_CODE is the last field header and the date (e.g., "2024-02-27") is the contents of the first populated field, if that makes sense. (I wasn't sure how best to present the source file contents, but if you take the description above and copy it into five vertical cells, then perform a data-to-columns conversion, you'll have my spreadsheet.)

Adrian, I'm not understanding your question #5 - What part of pgAdmin am I doing this in. I originally tried to use the Import/Export option from the drop-down list after right-clicking on the table name, but copied and amended the query in the Query Tool as it became apparent that the syntax being generated by the former was not being liked by the system. I hope that addresses the question.

Are those ** also in your actual CSV file?

I'm sorry - no, the "**"'s appear to have been added as a translation for strings I had put into bold font. All of the dates are simply YYYY-MM-DD strings. and there are no leading asterisks in the second field. I'll update the post to better reflect that.

The issue turned out to be that I did not note  the presence of a header line in the source data in the FROM statement. I changed "CSV ENCODING" to "CSV HEADER ENCODING" and all was good.
